# How can i read client request?

Tags: c#, httplistener

I have create an httplistener. So i need when client will send me data to read them. The problem is that i dont know how client should send the data

```
HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
        listener.Prefixes.Add("http://192.168.1.26:8282/");
        listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:8282/");
        listener.Prefixes.Add("http://127.0.0.1:8282/");

        listener.Start();
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;
            for (;;)
            {


                Console.WriteLine("Listening...");
                // Note: The GetContext method blocks while waiting for a request. 
                HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
                HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
                string text;
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(request.InputStream,
                                                     request.ContentEncoding))
                {
                    text = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    MessageBox.Show(text);
                }



                // Obtain a response object.
                HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
                // Construct a response.
                string responseString = "HelloWorld";
                byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);
                // Get a response stream and write the response to it.
                response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
                System.IO.Stream output = response.OutputStream;
                output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                // You must close the output stream.
                output.Close();

            }



        }).Start();

    }
```

So from client i send this command:

```
GET / 192.168.1.26:8282 HTTP/1.0
```

But i'm getting this message

```
    Recv 34 bytes

SEND OK

+IPD,1,518:HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Wed, 13 Jun 2018 13:16:03 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 339

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Header</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request has an invalid header name.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
1,CLOSED
```

I cant understand what is wrong. Also in my code i set to get a message box every time a request will happen. But it never runs

This s what mozilla is sending
[image]

Comment: The command you're sending from the client is invalid. The first line of an HTTP request has 3 fields, not 4. For example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Example_session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not attempting to invoke the service correctly. Here is your client request:

```
    GET / 192.168.1.26:8282 HTTP/1.0
```

What you should be doing is first establishing a socket connection to host 192.168.1.26 over port 8282. Then you must issue a HTTP request in a valid format:

```
    GET / HTTP/1.0
```

Don't forget to add some newlines after the request (ie: \r\n\r\n). Then your web server should respond to the HTTP request.

Quick example in Telnet:

```
    telnet 192.168.1.26 8282
    GET / HTTP/1.0
```

Quick example with netcat:

```
    nc 192.168.1.26 8282
    GET / HTTP/1.0
```

Note that these quick examples are provided just to help you ensure that your web service is accessible and functioning correctly. Ideally, you would likely use a more robust HTTP client that is customized for whatever your particular needs are. The process is still the same:

1. Establish a connection to your host IP address over the listening port
2. Issue a HTTP request in a valid format: (HTTP_VERB PATH HTTP_VERSION)

   *) Maybe check out the developer tools in your browser of choice (F12 -> Network) to see how HTTP headers are sent as well.
3. Parse the response in some meaningful way.

"Also in my code i set to get a message box every time a request will happen." - You should try putting in a manual message to the message box, instead of reading from the input stream. This is a good debugging technique. In a HTTP GET request you generally are not sending data except in the form of optional query string parameters. I have a feeling that you are not getting the results you are expecting because you are reading from input that isn't there. Before reading from the stream input, first make sure that the connection is successful.

Comment: First goes GET? How can i run a command like i open url in browser

Comment: In a browser, simply use the IP address and port to invoke your web service. For example: http://192.168.1.26:8282      The HTTP verb and path are actually added by the browser automatically (under the hood).

Comment: Since you seem to be more concerned with the browser interaction, open the developer tools of your browser (generally F12). Then navigate to the Networking section. Then, in the URL bar enter your IP address and port: 192.168.1.26:8282 . You should see how the browser actually formats the HTTP request within developer tools. Some browsers such as Firefox will actually let you edit the HTTP Verb (command), path, and other headers. If you want to play around with this in a browser I'd recommend Firefox and developer tools. Remember that for your command the browser automatically adds GET / HTTP

Comment: According to Mozilla i must send this but it doesnt work i get same error"GET\r\nhttp://192.168.1.26:8282/\r\n"

Comment: Again, the web browser adds GET and \r\n\r\n for you. You only need to provide the URL that includes your IP address and port. ONLY " http://192.168.1.26:8282 " should go in the URL field of the browser. If you inspect the network traffic you will see how the browser actually formats the HTTP request for you, without showing you in the URL field.

Comment: I found it it thanks i was this command GET /http://192.168.1.26:8282/\r\n